# How to get the return value of a function inside source in autocomplete function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete function which executes a function **customOutput()** inside it

```
  $(".search").autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
                    customOutput(request);
                    }
    });
```

**customOutput(request)** returns an array
How can I store the return value of customOutput(request) and use it in other function

Comment: Um, assign its result to a variable?  In other words, in the usual way?

Comment: Make an array variable with global scope and set it equal to `customOutput`

Comment: try return customOutput(request); in the function which returns the array

Comment: The function which returns the array is an ajax call so I cannot write return customOutput(request);

Comment: @sAaCh Then you'd use any of several mechanisms for handling the results of an async call.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your question, but if you want to save the RESPONSE that you are using for the customOutput function to be used in another function, you could declare an unassigned variable outside of the customOutput function and within the customOutput function to set it equal to RESPONSE. Then you should be able to use the response in another function.

Answer (score 0):

i use this and its work

```
var myObject = new Object();
$(".search").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
          myObject.myData = customOutput(request);
      }
});
```